# is there any way where we can call a vf page in trigger

Tags: salesforce

Is there any way where we can call vf page in a trigger?
As per my requirement,I need to insert a record through trigger and land it to another vf page.Is there any way we can call a vf page in trigger.

Please post with a functional code.

Comment: Please post the code that you have attempted to solve the issue

Comment: None here will do your work. We can help to understand if you you don't understand how to do smth. Explain your needs with more details. What is the use case. What do you want to be done after what user actions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to call visualforce page in a trigger.

If you try to insert a record on one VF page and after hitting Save you want to be redirected to a specific page, I suggest you to check [PageReference Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm).

After you call insert in a controller you should return a [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) instance with URL you want user to be redirected to.

Comment: I have tried the above  code above and have commented the page refrence,though uncommented was still not working

Comment: Please, try to understand what is Trigger (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) and what is what is Visualforce (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.pages.meta/pages/). Imagine, that VF runs in browser and trigger runs on Salesforce's server. While running on SF's server, trigger don't know anything about your browser, so it don't know where to output VF page. And there is no way to say to trigger where output your VF page.